# Why will my android notification not send?

Tags: android, firebase, notify

I am sending DATA payload from Postman, so the notification should be processed in onMessageReceived regardless of whether the app is in foreground or background.

According my logs and testing, onMessageReceived is fired, but the notifications are not showing (doesn't depend if the app is in foreground or background).

in manifest I have:

```
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service> <!-- [END firebase_iid_service] -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and here is MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String title = "";
        if (Objects.requireNonNull(remoteMessage.getData()).get("title") != null)
            title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");

        String message = "";
        if (Objects.requireNonNull(remoteMessage.getData()).get("message") != null)
            message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

        Log.e("notification",title);
        sendNotification(title, message);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String title, String body) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Novinky.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, // Request code
                i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
            getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notify)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setContentIntent(pi);

        NotificationManager manager =
                (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        assert manager != null;
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

So I have Log.e("notification",title); there, and it is executed properly, but the notify is not received.

Before I send also a notification+data via Postman, that worked, but that is only an automatic notification not handled by app, so now I want to send only DATA payload and handle it in the app, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: What version of android are you using?

Comment: testing on Android 8

Comment: Create a channel in your notification and pass it to the notification manager. it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have created your notification channel in your app. A good way to do this is as follows:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        createNotificationChannel();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel nChan = new NotificationChannel(
                getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id),
                "My_Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(nChan);
        }
    }
}
```

Creating your notification channel in the `onCreate()` of your app is a good idea as you don't have to worry about it for the rest of the application life time.

Comment: I am sending the DATA to the topics, so people are registered in firebase topic. I don't use any channel. { "to": "/topics/myTOPICS",

"data": {
   "title": "mytitle",
     "message": "mymessage",
     "sound" : "default"
  }
}

Comment: but finally I tried your solution with createNotificationChannel, I named it same as the topics, and now the notifications are working! Even if the app is killed, background or foreground. So thank you very much! Now I can also handle the translations for the title and message.

Comment: and just a small question - for android versions below 8? Will it work without channel?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it was a new feature in Oreo that you have to assign notifications to a channel, so maybe? It should work without it, in fact I'm nearly sure it does, but I don't want to give you an answer I'm not sure of but I imagine you could find out easily enough with a google search and a little bit of time.